# Deployment: old pod deletion selection

Tags: kubernetes

Which of the pods is killed in Deployment during rollout?

Eg: there is a deployment with `replicas: 2` and `maxUnavailable: 1`.

When you deploy a new version of the manifest 1 pod is killed while new version (new 2 pods) is rolled out. So which of the 2 is picked?

Answer (score 0):

As the new Pods in new version come online and are marked available,
any of the two pods can be killed by the Deployment controller upon rollout of the new version as they are exact replicas of the Deployment version 1

Comment: "any of the two pods can be killed by the Deployment controller" --- can this be confirmed by documentation or source code? My question is really - how exactly kubernetes makes a decision.